# Who is Movie Reel and what does he do?

Tags: support

Who is [moviereel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-119/movie-reel)? And what does he do? I find him everytime I visit the chat section. I beleive he is not a human like community. If so what does he do by posting the questions in chat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Movie Reel is one of two message feeds into the chat room - the other being Tomato Bot.  These are just automated services.  The purpose of Movie Reel is to bring to the attention of chat users of a new question being posted.

You can see information about the feeds [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1888/the-screening-room?tab=feeds).